# Clean a String to convert to int in Pandas

Tags: python, integer, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe in pandas, with a column named "Score". I have to do a rank,nevertheless in the column I have numbers like:
100
200
300
but also numbers like:
500,00
800,00

I need to clean this column to rank.

when I try to convert the string to int I got this error:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '610,00'

and when try to convert first to Float then integer i got:
could not convert string to float: '610,00'

I need to clean the column to the number dont be
500,00
800,00
etc,

but 500
800
610...

Comment: If the `,` is always a decimal separator (and not a thousands separator), perhaps you could first replace `,` with `.`

Answer (score 0):

@Jheison, expanding on what Swifty commented, if the comma is a decimal separator, as in some locales (Latin America, for example), you could do the following.

- You could directly modify the DataFrame

  ```py
  df["score"] = pd.to_numeric(df["score"].str.replace(",", "."), downcast="integer")
  ```

  Since you need to rank these, I suggest using the Pandas [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) function which you can choose which method to rank.

  > How to rank the group of records that have the same value (i.e. ties):
  >
  > - average: average rank of the group
  > - min: lowest rank in the group
  > - max: highest rank in the group
  > - first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
  > - dense: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups.

  Another key argument is if you're ranking these numbers in ascending order (1, 2, 3, ...) or not.

Lastly, I would have added the Pandas tag to your question.